# How can i remove span tags from elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove all the span tags having class article and attach a new span tags to the content

```
<div class="asd">
        <span class="location">Foo</span>  
        <span class="article">bar</span>   
        <span class="article">lorem</span>   
        <span class="article">ipsum</span>
</div>
```

In the javascript i've a text,

```
var text = "bar lorem ipsum";
```

I want javascript to find this in the DOM and if it is there, then remove the span tags from the elements and put all of them in a single span tag, like this

```
<div class="asd">
            <span class="location">Foo</span>  
            <span class="article">bar lorem ipsum</span>   
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you have attempted so far so we can help.

Comment: So, you want to merge the text from `span`s having same class? What should be result for `<span class="location">Lorem</span><span class="article">Foo</span><span class="location">Ipsum</span>`?

Comment: What is the problem? All I see is a requirement

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery `each()` function for this, check updated snippet below:

```js
var newHTML ='';
$('.asd span.article').each(function(){
  newHTML  += $(this).text() + " ";
  $(this).remove();
})
$('.asd').append("<span class='article'>"+newHTML+"</span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="asd">
        <span class="location">Foo</span>  
        <span class="article">bar</span>   
        <span class="article">lorem</span>   
        <span class="article">ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please let OP share effort. Do not spoon feed solution. SO is not **get code for free** portal

Comment: OK, will remember in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you check with jquery:

```
    <div class="asd">
    <span class="location">Foo</span>  
    <span class="article">bar</span>   
    <span class="article">lorem</span>   
    <span class="article">ipsum</span>
   </div>
```

Js

```
$(".article").remove();
$(".asd").append('<span class="article">bar lorem ipsum</span>');
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Please let OP share effort. Do not spoon feed solution. SO is not get code for free portal

Comment: Also, please explain what and why you have changed. You are answering for readers

Answer (score 0):

Try this .use with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function jquery .check the class name includes in  array .Is not Then pass the the  class name to array .
And also added the respected text with `eq(0)`(first element of same classname)

```js
var arr=[];
$('.asd').children('span').each(function(a){
var cls =$(this).attr('class');
if(!arr.includes(cls)){
arr.push(cls);
}
else{
$('.'+cls).eq(0).text($('.'+cls).eq(0).text()+' '+$(this).text())
$(this).remove()
}
})

console.log($('.asd').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="asd">
        <span class="location">Foo</span>  
        <span class="article">bar</span>   
        <span class="article">lorem</span>   
        <span class="article">ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Comment: First you should not answer a question without effort. It promotes spoon feeding. Second, if you still choose to answer, PLEASE add explanation. `Try this` is not an explanation